# circle rotated rectangle collision detection

Tags: html5-canvas, collision-detection

I am trying to implement the collision detection between rotated rectangle and circle by following this http://www.migapro.com/circle-and-rotated-rectangle-collision-detection/

I have added the code in jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Z6KSX/2/.

What am i missing here ?

```
function check_coll ( circle_x,circle_y, rect_x, rect_y, rect_width, rect_height, rect_angle) 
   {

    // Rotate circle's center point back
    var rect_centerX = rect_x /2 ;
    var rect_centerY = rect_y /2 ;

    var cx = (Math.cos(rect_angle) * (circle_x - rect_centerX)) - (Math.sin(rect_angle) * (circle_y - rect_centerY)) + rect_centerX;
    var cy = (Math.sin(rect_angle) * (circle_x - rect_centerX)) + (Math.cos(rect_angle) * (circle_y - rect_centerY)) + rect_centerY;

    // Closest point
    var x, y;

    // Find the unrotated closest x point from center of unrotated circle
    if (cx < rect_x) {
        x = rect_x;
    }
    else if (cx > rect_x + rect_width){
        x = rect_x + rect_width;
    }
    else{
        x = cx;
     }

    // Find the unrotated closest y point from center of unrotated circle
    if (cy < rect_y){
        y = rect_y;
    }
    else if (cy > rect_y + rect_height) {
        y = rect_y + rect_height;
    }
    else {
        y = cy;
     }
    // Determine collision
    var collision = false;

    var c_radius = 5;
    var distance = findDistance(cx, cy, x, y);

    if (distance < c_radius) {
        collision = true; // Collision
    }
    else {
        collision = false;
    }
     return collision;
}


function findDistance (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
       var a = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
       var b = Math.abs(y1 - y2);

       var c = Math.sqrt((a * a) + (b * b));
       return c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hehe, I find this amusing as I somewhat recently solved this for myself after spending a large amount of time going down the wrong path.

Eventually I figured out a way:

1.) Simply rotate the point of the center of the circle by the Negative amount the rectangle has been rotated by. Now the point is 'aligned' with the rectangle (in the rectangles relative coordinate space).

2.) Solve for circle vs. AABB. The way I solved it gave me a point on the rectangle that is closest to the circle's center.

3.) Rotate the resulting point from by the Positive amount the rectangle has been rotated by. Continue solving as usual (checking if the distance between that point and the circle center is within the circle's radius)

From a very quick glance at your code, it seems like maybe you are doing the same thing, but missing the last step? I suggest drawing out your point on the rectangle from step 2 to see exactly where it is to help debug.

Comment: I am unable to understand this can you please add some more details

Comment: It's a bit tough to tell from looking at your code, but what I mean is that circle vs. OOBB is the same as circle vs. AABB except that you need to rotate the center of the circle by the negative amount the rectangle has been rotated in then after the collision test (which you test as if it was for a circle vs. AABB), rotate the resulting point by the rectangle's rotation, and then use that point to check if it is within the circle.

Comment: is that the best way to to do that? rotating a vector and reverting this looks a bit heavy for me. there are ways using matrix in linear algebra. well, your answer may be the essence of these ways. but using angles scared me a bit

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out . The issue in the code was, I was using the wrong radius and had missed the center of rect_x and rect_y

```
   var rect_centerX = rect_x + (rect_width / 2);
   var rect_centerY = rect_y + (rect_height /2);
```

When dealing with rotation on the canvas we will need to add the translate values to the corresponding x and y values used in createrect.

Answer (score 0):

I also use this code for my project and it's working. The only thing you need to do is use -**angle** instead of the **angle**.

[Here is my code link](https://jsfiddle.net/Davit_Hakobyan2001/b8o73rau/1/)

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const rectX = 100;
const rectY = 100;
const rectWidth = 200;
const rectHeight = 100;
const circleRadius = 2;
const rectMidPointX = rectX + rectWidth / 2;
const rectMidPointY = rectY + rectHeight / 2;
const angle = Math.PI / 4;
let circleX;
let circleY;


canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  circleX = e.clientX;
  circleY = e.clientY;

  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
  ctx.arc(circleX, circleY, circleRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
    calculateIntersection();
})

ctx.save();

//ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.translate(rectMidPointX, rectMidPointY);
ctx.rotate(angle);
ctx.translate(-rectMidPointX, -rectMidPointY);
ctx.strokeRect(rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight);
ctx.restore();

// Determine collision
let collision = false;

const findDistance = (fromX, fromY, toX, toY) => {
  const a = Math.abs(fromX - toX);
  const b = Math.abs(fromY - toY);

  return Math.sqrt((a * a) + (b * b));
};


function calculateIntersection() {
  // Rotate circle's center point back
  const unrotatedCircleX = Math.cos(-angle) * (circleX - rectMidPointX) -
    Math.sin(-angle) * (circleY - rectMidPointY) + rectMidPointX;
  const unrotatedCircleY = Math.sin(-angle) * (circleX - rectMidPointX) +
    Math.cos(-angle) * (circleY - rectMidPointY) + rectMidPointY;

  // Closest point in the rectangle to the center of circle rotated backwards(unrotated)
  let closestX, closestY;

  // Find the unrotated closest x point from center of unrotated circle
  if (unrotatedCircleX < rectX)
    closestX = rectX;
  else if (unrotatedCircleX > rectX + rectWidth)
    closestX = rectX + rectWidth;
  else
    closestX = unrotatedCircleX;

  // Find the unrotated closest y point from center of unrotated circle
  if (unrotatedCircleY < rectY)
    closestY = rectY;
  else if (unrotatedCircleY > rectY + rectHeight)
    closestY = rectY + rectHeight;
  else
    closestY = unrotatedCircleY;

  const distance = findDistance(unrotatedCircleX, unrotatedCircleY, closestX, closestY);
  if (distance < circleRadius)
    collision = true; // Collision
  else
    collision = false;

  console.log('collision', collision);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400px" height="400px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I know this question is old but I wanted to post my solution to this because I've been struggling to find a good solution for days now. Here is how I solved this:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const rect = {
  x: 75,
  y: 75,
  centerX: 100,
  centerY: 100,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  color: "#9cffc6",
  rotation: 45
}
const circle = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  radius: 15,
  color: "#000000"
}

// gets rotated position of a point
function getRotatedPos(origin, point, angle) {
  const rotatedX = (Math.cos(angle) * (point.x - origin.x)) + (Math.sin(angle) * (point.y - origin.y)) + origin.x;
  const rotatedY = (Math.cos(angle) * (point.y - origin.y)) - (Math.sin(angle) * (point.x - origin.x)) + origin.y;

  return {
    x: rotatedX,
    y: rotatedY
  }
}

// converts degrees to radians
function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
  return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
}

// checks collision between the circle and rect
function checkCollision() {
  const radians = degreesToRadians(rect.rotation); // get the rotation of the rectangle in radians
  const origin = {
    x: rect.centerX,
    y: rect.centerY
  }

  const newCirclePos = getRotatedPos(origin, {x: circle.x, y: circle.y}, radians); // rotate the circle to the same axis as the rectangle

  let closestX;
  let closestY;

  // gets the closest x position on the rectangle to the circle
  if (newCirclePos.x < rect.x) closestX  = rect.x;
  else if (newCirclePos.x > rect.x + rect.width) closestX = rect.x + rect.width;
  else closestX = newCirclePos.x;

  // gets the closest y position on the rectangle to the circle
  if (newCirclePos.y < rect.y) closestY  = rect.y;
  else if (newCirclePos.y > rect.y + rect.height) closestY = rect.y + rect.height;
  else closestY = newCirclePos.y;

  // gets the distance of the closest point on the rectangle to the circle
  const distX = Math.abs(newCirclePos.x - closestX);
  const distY = Math.abs(newCirclePos.y - closestY);
  const distance = Math.sqrt((distX ** 2) + (distY ** 2));

  // if the distance is less than the circle's radius, there is a collision
  if (distance < circle.radius) return true;

  return false;
}

function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // clears the canvas
  
  // rotate the canvas
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(rect.x + rect.width / 2, rect.y + rect.height / 2);
  ctx.rotate(rect.rotation * Math.PI / 180);
  
  // if there is a collision, only the outline of the rect is drawn
  if (checkCollision()) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = rect.color;
    ctx.strokeRect(-rect.width / 2, -rect.height / 2, rect.width, rect.height);
  }
  else {
    ctx.fillStyle = rect.color;
    ctx.fillRect(-rect.width / 2, -rect.height / 2, rect.width, rect.height);
  }
  
  // restore the canvas to its original rotation
  ctx.restore();
  
  // draw the circle
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = circle.color;
  ctx.fill();
  
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

update();

// sets the circle's position to the mouse position
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const scaleX = canvas.width / rect.width;
  const scaleY = canvas.height / rect.height;

  const mouseX = (event.clientX - rect.left) * scaleX;
  const mouseY = (event.clientY - rect.top) * scaleY;
  
  circle.x = mouseX;
  circle.y = mouseY;
}, false);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

canvas {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>
```

**EDIT:**
I updated my answer to a simpler solution and I gave a better explanation.